# How To Setup Multiple Physics Bodies in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I need to have two physics bodies on my playerSprite. I need one body to be a smaller contact area and to only detect collisions on certain bodies. My code is inside my PlayerNode class is:

```
let walkingBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Door | PhysicsCategory.Wall | PhysicsCategory.SlideTerminator | PhysicsCategory.Shootable
let contactBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Monster | PhysicsCategory.Door | PhysicsCategory.Item | PhysicsCategory.Slide | PhysicsCategory.Teleport
let mainBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 40, height: 50))
mainBody.collisionBitMask = walkingBitMask
mainBody.contactTestBitMask = contactBitMask
    
let pitBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 8, height: 8))
pitBody.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Pit
pitBody.collisionBitMask = 0
    
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(bodies: [mainBody,pitBody])
self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
self.name = "player"
self.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
```

The Pit category is all I want to interact with the pitBody. My code in setting up the Pit sprites is:

```
sprite.physicsBody=SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 8, height: 8))
sprite.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
sprite.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
sprite.name = "pit"
sprite.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
sprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Pit
sprite.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
```

The problem I'm running into is that the player sprite stops moving when it encounters a pit sprite. Everything else works fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a physics body using [`SKPhysicsBody.init(bodies:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519736-init), ***the properties on the children are ignored. Only the shapes of the child bodies are used***, according to the docs.

So the test bit masks specified on `mainBody` and `pitBody` are ignored, and the compound body of the player that is part of the simulation only specifies the `categoryBitMask`:

```swift
self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
```

This means it will collide with other bodies, since it's [`collisionBitMask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520003-collisionbitmask) default value is 0xFFFFFFFF (all bits set).

Configure the `collisionBitMask` and `contactTestBitMask` on the player body.
If you need to use separate collisions, consider using a [`SKPhysicsJointFixed`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsjointfixed)  to fuse the two physics bodies together.